# I'm learning laravel 8, and not understanding how this syntax works

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8, crud, one-to-many

i'm making an app with a one to many relationships. A user has many posts.

in the web.php (the route file)

we wrote

```
Route::get('/insert', function () {
    $user=User::findOrFail(1);
    $post= new Post(['title'=>'title1','body'=>'bd1']);
    $user -> posts()->save($post);
});
```

could anyone explain
the second and third line?

```
2- $user=User::findOrFail(1);
3- $post= new Post(['title'=>'title1','body'=>'bd1']);
```

why did we write User, new Post? how did this work?

Comment: You could have found this yourself by searching the Laravel documentation: [Not Found Exceptions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions) and [Inserting & Updating Models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) should help

Answer (score 0):

With this command (line 2-) you are trying to find the user with id number 1

```
2- $user=User::fin`enter code here`dOrFail(1);
```

With this line of code (line 3-), you are inserting in the database a new record of type Post(defined in your Models directory) with the fields "title" and "body". You need to specify the user who is the author of the post:

```
3- $post= new Post(['title'=>'title1','body'=>'bd1']);
```

With the next line of code you are going to insert in the database a new record of type Post with the user you have found in your request ($user=User::findOrFail(1);)

```
Post::create(
['title' => 'title1', 'body' => 'bd1', 'user_id' = $user]);
```